# SQL - last datetime

Tags: sql, datetime

I have select

```
select  FisrtTable.[Date and Time],FisrtTable.[New Value],SecondTable.[Registering Date]
from FisrtTable
join SecondTable
on FisrtTable.[New Value] = SecondTable.[New Value] 
where SecondTable.[Registering Date] >= '26-05-2015  0:00'
```

I need select to retrieve last datetime by [New Value], I have

[image]

but I want only the last row by time

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below query.

```
with cte_1
as
(select  FisrtTable.[Date and Time],FisrtTable.[New Value],SecondTable.[Registering Date],
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY FisrtTable.[New Value] ORDER BY FisrtTable.[Date and Time] desc) RNO
from FisrtTable
join SecondTable
on FisrtTable.[New Value] = SecondTable.[New Value] 
where SecondTable.[Registering Date] >= '26-05-2015  0:00')

SELECT [Date and Time],[New Value],[Registering Date]
FROM cte_1
WHERE RNO=1
```

Answer (score 0):

***`Simply`*** select **`TOP 1` Record *`ordering`* the entire result in `DESC`**

```
Select 
top 1 st.datefield, st.*
from SomeTable st
Order by st.datefield desc
```

Comment: in that case ,simply remove top 1 and try the same.

Comment: and what do you mean by "Last Row" ?

Comment: I want if [New value] has more datetime to get only row by  last time